# what is the relationship between 人間多様性,, 人格 and 由来 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

「人間多様性は本来、人格の多様性に由来している」

Human diversity is the basis, (which makes something) diversity of personality??

Having particular difficult with 由来 にする。　由来 = origin/source... put する on it to make it a verb and it means originate.

would 'human diversity is fundamentally the basis of diversity of personality' be a correct translation?

Does Aに由来する mean, originates from A? these are my best guesses, would appreciate any clarification

Comment: That comma is just to separate 本来 and 人格 (without it, one may see a
 strange word "本来人格"). There is only one clause in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct. I'd translate. ***Human diversity by nature based on the diversity of personality.*** A に由来する means **originate/derived from A**

Answer (score 2):

***Basically, human diversity comes from the diversity of each individual's personality, (not from race, nationality, or religion).***

~~に由来する＝come from ~~, due to ~~

In this specific context, you may think that に由来する is translated as "means" or "indicates."